# In comments, why do SE-origin URLs not render as the title automatically?

Tags: feature-request

In many places on SE, if you paste the URL of a question or answer, it is displayed as the title of the question/answer, rather than the URL. After I noticed this, I expected it to be the case everywhere -- but, bafflingly, this is not the case for comments. I think it would be aesthetically appealing and helpful to render titles in comments. After all, the URL is currently truncated after so many characters, so clicking on a URL in a comment is totally blind.

Comment: Oh yes, how many times did I wish it were implemented.

Comment: Hmm. It has status-declined here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394. Jeff Atwood himself answered that this would not be done and his answer has score -49 whereas an answer saying it should be done has +76. Wow. Quite a discrepancy between the public opinion and the official position.

Comment: Well, according to Mr. Atwood, it's just a question of database load. It's a plausible explanation, so it would appear that people aren't frustrated with Jeff so much as with the state of databases? In any case, when you VTC a question as a dupe, the title *is* displayed -- so there must be something else afoot. I don't understand why whatever magic is used when VTC-ing a question can't also be used when linking outside of the VTC interface.

Comment: A lot of things aren't done as nicely in the comments as elsewhere. HTML code doesn't work properly (eg, &mdash; doesn't render "—").

Comment: @amoeba, it's also interesting that it was given a +500 bounty! How many -49 / +500 posts do you think there are in the SE system?

Comment: @gung I'd wager precisely 1. But that must be an artifact of when rep was recorded separately across meta and main communities.

Comment: I sometimes construct a title-link when putting links in comments myself by pasting int the title into a `[...](...)` -style link: `[question title here](url-here)`.

Comment: @user777 note that meta.SE doesn't have a "main site"

Comment: @Glen_b, I think he's thinking about when there was only meta.SO (before they made a separate meta.SE).